# Javascript to add future dates to embedded data in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, date, qualtrics

I'm being asked to integrate JavaScript into Qualtrics to accomplish the following three steps:

1. Get the current date in UTC format and convert to ISO 8601.
2. Use the current date in the prior step to create a future date (i.e., 3 months from now).
3. Assign the value of the date generated in #2 to an embedded data field.

**Note**: This isn't in my wheelhouse and I'm having quite a bit of trouble accomplishing this task.

Here's a snippet of code that I've generated thus far:

```
//add 3 months from current date;
var someDateM3 = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 90;
someDateM3.setDate(someDateM3.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
var month3 = someDateM3.toISOString();

//assign value of month3 to embedded data field 'month3';
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addEmbeddedData( 'month3', "${e://Field/month3}");
```

Am I on the right track? I lack the training and skillset required to complete this seemingly straightforward task. Any advice would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your date calculation is fine.  The problem is with saving it to an embedded data variable.  That should be:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('month3', month3);
```

You need to define the embedded data variable month3 in the survey flow prior to the block that contains the question with your date calculation JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between setEmbeddedData and addEmbeddedData! I have month3 defined as an embedded data variable in the survey flow prior to the block, but does it need a value to be assigned to it in the survey flow?

Comment: No, you don't need to assign a value to month3.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but you don't actually need javascript to accomplish any of this, if you did not want to.

You can directly [pipe date into an embedded data variable](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/editing-questions/piped-text/piped-text-overview/#PipingDateTime). You can custom format how you want that date to appear using [PHP Date Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). You can then set relative dates again using [PHP Syntax for relative datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) and using "OtherDate" Instead of "CurrentDate" when in the embedded data. Just make sure to encode the syntax for both like you would a url (%20 for space, etc).

I believe it should look something like this (replace my Y-m-d with whatever formatting you'd need if that's not it):

```
${date://OtherDate/Y-m-d/%2B3%20month} (or /%2B90%20day instead if you want to mimic exactly what your code is doing).
```

Comment: This would be really cool if it worked. Alas, it doesn't. The PHP Date Syntax only works if it is Y/m/d, m/d/Y, or d/m/Y (only with slashes, e.g. Y%2Fm%2Fd). Y-m-d or any other PHP Date Syntax doesn't work.

Comment: I tried one more thing. It turns out you can use Y, m, and d by themselves.  So, this works to give you YYYY-MM-DD in 3 months: ${date://OtherDate/Y/+3 month}-${date://OtherDate/m/+3 month}-${date://OtherDate/d/+3 month}

Comment: I never noticed that Y-m-d gives a weird month when you try it. Thanks for catching that, i'll add that to my notes for future reference.